# Android Studio failed build NDK project non-zero exit value

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-ndk

I imported a project that I was working on from an Eclipse Android SDK environment to the new Android Studio.
Trying to run the project I get this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'ndk/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

So first of all for me it's weird to see this error, because working in Eclipse Android SDK before, I ran ndk-build by myself which I still do. So is Android Studio running ndk-build for me now? Because when I run it in Terminal I have no problem at all and here it tells me bad exit-value.

And then I searched on the internet and found a "quick fix", which is to create an empty .c file, because you can't build/run ndk project with no .c files. This, not surprisingly, does not work for me because we have plenty of .c files in the .jni folder.

Just to mention I'm on a Macbook Pro under Yosemite, and the project should have no problems in itself.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: did you find any solutions for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known problem of Android Studio, caused by very limited support of NDK-enabled projects. Answering to your question: yes, Android Studio now run ndk-build on its own, but it ignore existing Android.mk and generate one on the fly (and do it wrong for any non-trivial NDK-enabled project). Practically, the best way to fix this is to disable Android Studio's limited NDK support and call ndk-build from gradle script. [Here](https://www.crystax.net/blog/3) I've described it more detailed and how to get it fixed.

Comment: Yeah It was superb Thanks

Comment: you're the man with the master plan mr Dmitry! Thanks so much. I was stuck for a few hours.

Comment: android-studio preview 22 now have section to include cmake\ndk-build makefiles

Comment: @hay Dmitry i have the same issue i tried everything i found on web for 2 Days now! i even tried example in your blog i still get the same Error. any idea/suggestion to solve this issue? AS last version, gradle 2.2 target and compiled SDK 24 and 23 tried both

Comment: I can confirm that this happens in AndroidStudio 2.3 and InteliJ 2016.3 + Android plugin.

Comment: I'm following the process on the link - do we have a download file of Crystax NDK for mac?

Comment: Only solution which worked! thank you very Mr. @Dmitry Moskalchuk. Grateful to you.

Answer (score 2):

For simple, you can try to insert `sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []` to `android` block in build.gradle file. This will tell gradle to look for your C++ files in different path.

Answer (score 2):

To see what is the exact problem do these:
**1-** Make sure you have set ndk path correctly, for example in my project I put `ndk.dir=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk-r13b`  in `local.properties` file
**2-** Go to app directory of your android app
**3-** Run this command: `<ndk_build_path> -C <jni_path> NDK_OUT=<jniLibDir> all NDK_DEBUG=1`
example :

```
/usr/local/opt/android-ndk-r13b/ndk-build -C /MYAPP/app/src/main/jni -j 4 NDK_OUT=../jniLibs all NDK_DEBUG=1
```

then you can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered same error while importing a project from windows to mac, I tried all the above solutions, did not work. Finally noticed that there were "multiple target patterns" which was causing this error.

**Solution** : Delete the "obj" folder within your NDK and rebuild.

Done !!

Comment: Thanks, this was my exact issue. It's remarkable how many different root causes will trigger this error

Answer (score 1):

You can disable **compileDebugNdk**, but still have the **jni** folder visible in Android Studio. In your **build.gradle**, add the following clause:

```
tasks.all { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('compile') && task.name.endsWith('Ndk')) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost tried every solution available. I use Windows 10, Android Studio 1.5.1 and the only thing that worked, is the solution here (http://answers.opencv.org/question/58551/androidstudiondk-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value2/)

In the Apps>build.gradle, add this under the android object.

```
android{
...
sourceSets { 
 main { 
      res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res'] 
      jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs'] 
      jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk 
 } 
}
```

In this version of Android Studio, adding the NDK path in File>Project Structure>NDK Path automatically adds it to local.properties file, you **don't edit anything else.**

Comment: @abggcv Do you still get the same non-zero exit error? If you are using Windows you might want to avoid spaces name of the folder path. It was one of the suggestions I learned somewhere.
 
Also check out the [link](https://www.crystax.net/blog/3) given by Dmitry Moskalchuk and from that - make sure the folder structure is correct, create Android,mk and application.mk files if they are not already there in app/src/main/jni .
I used the following tutorial to setup opencv + the above modifications [link](https://youtu.be/JIHfqzTdOcQ) Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using ubuntu. There are no spaces but I later discovered that the issue got resolved when I removed the CMakeList from project and used only the Android.mk file. Actually in the latest android studio C++ support is provided and it was automatically creating cmake files and including it in build.gradles. I am used to the Android.mk file so I removed the cmake support. I found [this](https://github.com/leadrien/opencv_native_androidstudio) github project working for latest android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and try many things but not work and I found out:

commandLine ndkBuildPath, '-j8', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath

Please try this:

Go to src/main/jni, open terminal and run command: /home/.../Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build

It will build and show more log. You will get what wrong in your code.