# Android Studio NDK - finished with non-zero exit value 2 when I try to run libpd sample projects

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, puredata, libpd

I install libpd with this commands (I use Android Studio 2.2.3)

```
$ git clone git://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android.git
$ cd pd-for-android
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Then, I imported the sample libpd projects and pd-for-android library (as select root folder pd-for-android)
Everything looks good until press run button.

I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':PdCore:buildNative'.
> Process 'command 'C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I tried many things to install libpd. How would I install Pure Data for Android step by step?

Comment: First, try to build the library from command line (to separate problems caused by gradle and Android Studio). Try to run `ndk-build V=1` to have step-by-step output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio failed build NDK project non-zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605029/android-studio-failed-build-ndk-project-non-zero-exit-value)