# Error finding ndk-bundle in Android Studio, but it exists and is in the right place

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-ndk

**Context**

I'm not an app developer, and I hardly know what I'm doing myself.

For my thesis I'm making maps with an app (tango_ros_streamer). I needed to change someway it makes the map by taking out literally 3 lines in the code. To do this, I require to build the app on the phone again.

**What I've done**

I'm on Linux 16.04 , working with ROS Kinetic.

I've installed Android Studio, and installed the NDK plugin(?). I've confirmed with `/opt/android-studio$ ls`that indeed, `ndk-bundle` exists and is not empty.

In the Android Studio, File > Project Structure > Android NDK Location: is indeed `/opt/android-sdk/ndk-bundle`.

In `local.properties` it is also

```
sdk.dir=/opt/android-sdk
ndk.dir=/opt/android-studio/ndk-bundle
```

**Problem**

However, when the phone is connected in Developer mode to the computer, and I 'run' the Android Studio code, it gets and error at 'Run build > Run tasks' namely:

> Process 'command '/opt/android-sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished
>   with non-zero exit value 2

I'm literally just picking up Android Studio just to fix this tiny bit of code, I have no experience at all with app development. So I'll do my best to understand, but be aware I'm still a novice. I've looked at other answers to similar problems with ndk but can't seem to find a solution that works for me. In easy terms, what am i doing wrong? Can you see what's wrong with my folders or files? 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605029/android-studio-failed-build-ndk-project-non-zero-exit-value

Comment: This app was built a while ago, and tuned for NDK r10. It's quite likely that the build scripts are not compatible with the latest NDK r16. Please download r10 from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases and follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/Intermodalics/tango_ros/blob/master/README.md). At any rate, 'non-zero exit value' does not mean 'error finding ndk-bundle', but rather a 'build error'.

Comment: @Alex_Cohn i've downloaded ndk-r10e, got the location in Project Structure and local.properties correctly pointing at it, did a Clean Project, everything, still same error. `/ndk-build returns non-zero exit value 2`